# Have the same size on all my boxes

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox

I currently use this code to create my boxes :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{before=\centering, hbox, drop fuzzy shadow, enhanced}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}
\begin{large}
\begin{flushleft}

gfdsgsdgsd gdssssssssssssssssssssssssssffffgdsffffffffffffffffffffffffffff\\
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{mybox}
$\begin{aligned}
a\leq b \Leftrightarrow ac \leq bc
\end{aligned}$
\end{mybox}

gfdsgsdgsd gdssssssssssssssssssssssssssffffgdsffffffffffffffffffffffffffff\\
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{mybox}
$\begin{aligned}
1+1=2
\end{aligned}$
\end{mybox}

gfdsgsdgsd gdssssssssssssssssssssssssssffffgdsffffffffffffffffffffffffffff\\
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{mybox}
$\begin{aligned} 
gdssssssssssssssssssssssss
\end{aligned}$
\end{mybox}

\end{flushleft}
\end{large}
\end{document}
```

I'd like all my boxes to be the width of my biggest box.

How can I do that? thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: @Andrew Hi, I'm sorry I edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that very easily with the `eqparbox` package (two compilations are necessary):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{before=\centering, hbox, drop fuzzy shadow, enhanced}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}

\begin{large}
\begin{flushleft}

gfdsgsdgsd gdssssssssssssssssssssssssssffffgdsffffffffffffffffffffffffffff\\
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{mybox}
\eqmakebox[M]{$\begin{aligned}
a\leq b \Leftrightarrow ac \leq bc
\end{aligned}$}
\end{mybox}

gfdsgsdgsd gdssssssssssssssssssssssssssffffgdsffffffffffffffffffffffffffff\\
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{mybox}
\eqmakebox[M]{$\begin{aligned}
1+1=3
\end{aligned}$}
\end{mybox}

gfdsgsdgsd gdssssssssssssssssssssssssssffffgdsffffffffffffffffffffffffffff\\
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{mybox}
\eqmakebox[M]{$\begin{aligned}
gdssssssssssssssssssssssss
\end{aligned}$}
\end{mybox}

\end{flushleft}
\end{large}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's working.
It is not possible in only 1 compilation? On my application, two compilations will be problematic in some cases.

Currently I use hspace{Xcm} but it's heavy to do...

Comment: LaTeX has to determine first which is the widest box, before setting all boxes to this width. Note that for another series, with a possibly different common width, you have to chage the eqmakebox tag (the letter `M` here). Maybe you could add this tag as an optional argument of  the `mybox` environment and this construction in the definition of the environment? I don't know enough of `tcolorbox` to do that.

Comment: On my app, I select random texts that I compile in latex, calling the compilation twice would slow down the program considerably.
Otherwise, it's not possible to check myself the size of the biggest box and to wedge all the others on it?

Comment: You can try with `\makebox[\mylength]{...}`, where you define \mylength as `\widthof{longest formula}` (you also should add 2\fboxsep).

Comment: Is it possible to write that in the preamble? 
I'm a latex rookie.

Comment: I use a lot of boxes that I center with my mathematical writings, but if they don't have the same width, I think it's ugly, that's why I'd like to balance all of them as simply as possible since I use a lot of them and in 1 compilation otherwise I'd have bugs...

Comment: In this case, you can use a code like this in the preamble: `\newlength{\tcbwidth}
\settowidth{\tcbwidth}{$gdssssssssssssssssssssssss$}\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{before=\centering, hbox, drop fuzzy shadow, enhanced, width=\tcbwidth}`..

Comment: Finally it works, thanks, you just had to remove hbox.

Comment: I wonder whether `hbox` isn't the default ?

Comment: hbox allows you to adapt the box to the text.
It therefore prevented the modification you proposed to me